# Using localStorage in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Novice in React.

I have a DropDown field with 2 input areas with `text` and `number` properties. After I setup the data it stored them in the list order. Check the below screen shot `ADABTC 400 (2020-7-30 7:25:15)`

[image]

After I refresh page this string disappears. How can I store it so that it will stay after page is refreshed? Is there any better alternatives in React to store data instead of `localStorage`?

**CODE**

```
 import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const assets = [
  "ADABTC",
  "AIONBTC",
  "ALGOBTC",
  "ARDRBTC",
  "KAVABTC",
  "ETHBTC",
  "ETCBTC"
];

export default function App() {
  const [queries, setQueries] = useState([]);
  const [symbol, setSymbol] = useState("");
  const [price, setPrice] = useState("");
  const [dropdown, setDropdown] = useState([]);

  const onChangeSymbol = e => {
    setSymbol(e.target.value);
  };

  const onChangePrice = e => {
    setPrice(e.target.value);
  };

  var today = new Date();
  var date =
    today.getFullYear() + "-" + (today.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + today.getDate();
  var time =
    today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
  var dateTime = date + " " + time;

  const onClick = () => {
    if (symbol !== "" && price !== "") {
      setQueries(queries => {
        return [
          ...queries,
          `${symbol}` + " " + `${price}` + " " + "(" + dateTime+")"
        ];
      });
      setSymbol("");
      setPrice("");
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (symbol !== "" && symbol !== assets.find(rec => rec === symbol)) {
      setDropdown(assets.filter(rec => rec.indexOf(symbol) > -1));
    } else {
      setDropdown([]);
    }
  }, [symbol]);

  return (
    <div id="DropDownArea" className="DropDownField">
      <div id="PriceAlertHistory">
        <h6>Price Alert History</h6>
      </div>
      <ul>
        {queries.map(query => (
          <li>{query}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Symbol"
        value={symbol}
        onChange={onChangeSymbol}
      />
      <input
        type="number"
        placeholder="Price"
        value={price}
        onChange={onChangePrice}
      />
      <button type="submit" onClick={onClick}>
        Set
      </button>
      <ul>
        {dropdown.length !== 0
          ? dropdown.map(asset => {
              return (
                <li
                  onClick={() => {
                    setSymbol(asset);
                    setDropdown([]);
                  }}
                >
                  {asset}
                </li>
              );
            })
          : false}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: It's pretty common to persist app state to local storage. Have you tried that and have an issue? or just looking for suggestions?

Comment: I think you have 3 options to persist data: localStorage/sessionStorage/cookie, url, or backend (database).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const assets = [
  "ADABTC",
  "AIONBTC",
  "ALGOBTC",
  "ARDRBTC",
  "KAVABTC",
  "ETHBTC",
  "ETCBTC"
];

export default function App() {
  const [queries, setQueries] = useState(
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("queries")) || []
  );
  const [symbol, setSymbol] = useState("");
  const [price, setPrice] = useState("");
  const [dropdown, setDropdown] = useState([]);

  const onChangeSymbol = e => {
    setSymbol(e.target.value);
  };

  const onChangePrice = e => {
    setPrice(e.target.value);
  };

  var today = new Date();
  var date =
    today.getFullYear() + "-" + (today.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + today.getDate();
  var time =
    today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
  var dateTime = date + " " + time;

  const onClick = () => {
    if (symbol !== "" && price !== "") {
      setQueries(queries => {
        const query =
          `${symbol}` + " " + `${price}` + " " + "(" + dateTime + ")";
        localStorage.setItem(
          "queries",
          `[${[...queries, query].map(rec => `"${rec}"`)}]`
        );
        return [...queries, query];
      });
      setSymbol("");
      setPrice("");
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (symbol !== "" && symbol !== assets.find(rec => rec === symbol)) {
      setDropdown(assets.filter(rec => rec.indexOf(symbol) > -1));
    } else {
      setDropdown([]);
    }
  }, [symbol]);

  return (
    <div id="DropDownArea" className="DropDownField">
      <div id="PriceAlertHistory">
        <h6>Price Alert History</h6>
      </div>
      <ul>
        {queries.map(query => (
          <li>{query}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Symbol"
        value={symbol}
        onChange={onChangeSymbol}
      />
      <input
        type="number"
        placeholder="Price"
        value={price}
        onChange={onChangePrice}
      />
      <button type="submit" onClick={onClick}>
        Set
      </button>
      <ul>
        {dropdown.length !== 0
          ? dropdown.map(asset => {
              return (
                <li
                  onClick={() => {
                    setSymbol(asset);
                    setDropdown([]);
                  }}
                >
                  {asset}
                </li>
              );
            })
          : false}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Backend save your data into your database and then read those data when page reloads. You can do this inside `componentDidMount()` method.

Or else if you don't have a Backend then you can store your data in `localStorage`, `sessionStorage` or as `Cookies` . There are some differences between those 3 methods. Choose the one which suits you requirement.

Answer (score 0):

`queries` is populated only in `onClick()`. So when  you refresh the page, it gets reinitialized. LocalStorage would work since data is persisted until the browser cache is cleared by the user manually or until the data is cleared by your app.

[This shows a good guide](https://www.robinwieruch.de/local-storage-react) to use local storage in react, among other things.